# Filtering logic too strict

Tags: javascript, json, filter, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to filter JSON data using the `input[type="range"]` element. I've reached a point where the filter works but it doesn't work perfectly.

Assume the default `filters` object looks like this:

```
filters = {
  price: 100,
  rating: 3,
  beds: 1,
  people: 1
}
```

Using this concept, and changing the values of the `filters` on `input` event the apartments get filtered very strictly, taking into consideration default values and the values the user actually wanted to filter by.

```
apartments = apartments.filter(apartment => {
    if (typeof apartment.price == 'string') {
        apartment.price = apartment.price.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    }
    if (apartment.price <= (filters.price - 100) ||
        apartment.price >= filters.price) {
            return false;
    }
    if (apartment.rating != filters.rating)
        return false;
    if (apartment.beds != filters.beds)
        return false;
    if (apartment.people != filters.people)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
});
```

The question here is:

How can I make the filter better by only taking into account the value of the filter that the user changed?

I tried simply removing the default values but in that case there can never be a match for the filter because a value doesnt exist, and by putting a default value the apartments are strictly filtered with all 4 values even if the user only changed one of them.

Here is how the filters look on my app:
http://prntscr.com/e6h3oq

This is one apartment represented in JSON:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "title":"ultrices posuere cubilia curae",
    "description":"Suspendisse potenti. In eleifend quam a odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.\n\nMaecenas ut massa quis augue luctus tincidunt. Nulla mollis molestie lorem. Quisque ut erat.",
    "date":"3/9/2016",
    "price":"£200.32",
    "rating":2,
    "address":"7 Harbort Drive",
    "beds":2,
    "people":2,
    "user":{
        "first_name":"Douglas",
        "last_name":"Hansen",
        "email":"dhansen0@skype.com",
        "phone":"66-(363)851-6428"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to check if property is set in filter object. 
If it is `undefined` then return `true` from filter.

I would refactor your code a little bit:

Your check for beds, people and rating is very similar, so I would move it to curried function like this:

```
const propertyFilter = (propertyName) => {
       return (appartment) => {
           if(filters[propertyName] != undefined) {
               return  filters[propertyName]== apartment[propertyName]);
           }
           return true;
       }
}
```

You could also introduce function to handle parse logic of price and avoid mixing it with filtering code.

```
const parsePrice = (price) => {
    if (typeof price == 'string') {
            price = price.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    }
    return price;
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
apartments
.filter(propertyFilter("people"))
.filter(propertyFilter("beds"))
.filter(propertyFilter("rating"))
.filter(apartment => {
    if(apartment.price != undefined) {
        const price = parsePrice(apartment.price);
        if (price <= (filters.price - 100) || price >= filters.price) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
})
```